# Aligning sections next to another

Tags: html, css

How do we align 2 sections next to another section that has the same height as the other two sections combined, WITHOUT using float?

**Update:**
My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="header-main">
    <div class="header-left">
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
        <div class="cont-top">
            <div class="header-top-left">
            </div>
            <div class="header-top-right">
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="header-bottom">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS like this:

```
div.header-left
{
    width:160px;
    height:182px;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.header-right
{
    width:730px;
    height:182px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div.header-top
{
    width:730px;
    height:125px;
}

div.header-top-left
{
    width:340px;
    height:123px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div.header-top-right
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:380px;
    height:123px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:right;
}

div.header-bottom
{
    width:730px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Seem to work fine now. Personally I think its easier to control elements this way than to use float.

Any comments are appreciated.
I hope it may be useful for someone :).

Comment: I'd like to illustrate with an image but my rep is too low :)

Comment: you can do it using display: inline-block

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question with examples of the code you have tried, and even a link to a codepen or other coding playground

Answer (score 0):

Is this the layout you were trying for?

```
### ###
#1# ###
### ###
    #3#
### ###
#2# ###
### ###
```

If so you could do with `flexbox` or using inline-block as Tushar mentioned ... but please consider how this will look on mobile devices.

Comment: I will try this and and thanks for the heads up about the mobile look.

Comment: Use flexbox! It's the layout method of the future!.

For mobile just make everything stack vertically.